# Update user got error when disable userid input field

Tags: angular, typescript

I got error `Error: User not found.` when I trying to update user profile. Seem like it not send my userId. But when I enable userId input field it working. I dont have any idea how to solve it. Hope you all can help.

**HTML**

```
    <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)" class="form-horizontal row-border">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-2 control-label color-label">User ID</label>
      <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 padding-left">
        <input matInput type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="userId"
                                                [ngModel]="selectedRow?.userId" [disabled]="selectedRow?.userId" id="userId"
                                                required>
         </div>
         </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-2 control-label color-label">User Name</label>
     <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-left">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-5">
     <input matInput type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="userName"
                                                    [ngModel]="selectedRow?.userName" id="userName" required>
     </div>

     <label class="col-md-2 control-label color-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-md-5 padding-left">
       <input matInput type="email" class="form-control form-input" name="email"
                                                    [ngModel]="selectedRow?.email" id="email" required>
       </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<div class="pt-md-3 col-md-11 text-right a_bottom">
   <button type="submit" mat-flat-button color="primary"
                                    [disabled]="isValidForm(userForm)">{{submitButtonLabel}}</button>
 <button type="reset" mat-flat-button color="basic"
                                    (click)="hideUserForm()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

**Component**

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm ){
    let data = form.value;
    // data.groups = [].concat(this.groups).toString();
    let method = this.selectedRow ? 'updateUserProfile' : 'createUserProfile';
    this.userProfile[method](new User(data)).subscribe(res => {
      if(method== 'updateUserProfile'){
        this.toastrService.success('update succeeded!');
      }else{
        this.toastrService.success('create new user succeeded');
      }
        this.loadUsers();  
        this.hideUserForm();    
    }, err =>{
      console.error(err);  
    });
  }
```

Comment: `[ngModel]="selectedRow?.userId"` it's not work plz change like this `[(ngModel)]="selectedRow.userId"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. you can use the following for it to work if you are using form group:

```
fonSubmit(form: NgForm ){
    let data = this.fg.getRawValue();
    // Rest of the code
```

Check documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

> getRawValue()
>   The aggregate value of the FormGroup, including any disabled controls.
>
> Retrieves all values regardless of disabled status. The value property
>   is the best way to get the value of the group, because it excludes
>   disabled controls in the FormGroup.

If you go with the form value, then you need to use readonly like this:

```
[readonly]="selectedRow?.userId"
```

> The disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from using the
>    element until some other condition has been met (like
>   selecting a checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript could remove the
>   disabled value, and make the  element usable.
>
> Tip: Disabled  elements in a form will not be submitted!

Comment: I had added code `let data = form.getRawValue()` but I got error `Property 'getRawValue' does not exist on type 'NgForm'`

Comment: Sorry, you need to get these from the FormGroup not the ngForm.

Comment: I'm not using FormGroup

Comment: I updated the answer to account for NgForm only solution with readonly.